# How to assign multiple variables to a FIXED sized "table" output

Tags: bash

I want to parse a **mediainfo** output and assign each line to its own variable.

My problem is that if the number of lines of the output changes, then the logical value of the var also changes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function tester_mediainfo() {
    
    #this must be done with the hard new line, its a mediainfo quirk 
template="General;%OverallBitRate/String%|
Video;%Width%|%Height%|%FrameRate/String%|%DisplayAspectRatio/String%|%ScanType/String%|%FrameRate/String%|%ChromaSubsampling/String%|%BitDepth%|%InternetMediaType%|%Format/String%|%Format_Profile%|%Format_Settings%|%BitRate_Mode/String%|%BitRate_Nominal/String%|%BitRate_Maximum/String%|%ColorSpace%|
Audio;%BitRate/String%|%Format/String%|%Channel(s)/String%|%BitRate_Mode/String%|%BitRate/String%|%SamplingRate/String%"

maker=$(mediainfo --Output="$template" "$1" | sed 's/video\///g' | tr '|' '\n '| awk '{ print $1 }')

read -r A B C D E F G H I J K L M N< <(echo $maker)
}

tester_mediainfo $1
```

I want to be able to output a list of variables to be used in **IF** statements later, thus the logical meaning of them cannot change!

let's say the script outputs:

```
output:     variable:
15.7            A 
25.000      B                   #this changes 
16:9            C
MBAFF           D
25.000      E           #this changes 
4:2:0           F
8                   G
H264            H
AVC             I
High            J
CABAC           K
```

that's 11 lines of output.

Right now, what happens is that if I run the script again on a different mediafile:

```
output:     variable:
10.5                A
16:9                B
Progressive C
4:2:0               D
8                       E
H264                F
AVC                 G
Main@L4.1       H
CABAC               I
Constant        J
10                  K
```

**25.000** FPS (line 2) and it would be assigned to var B

**16:9** Aspect Ratio (line2) and it would be assigned to var B should have been null

Comment: Why using different variables? You could us an associative array, where you have keys such as `aspect_ratio`, and fill in the value based on what's available in the output. Of course you need to know for this, which of the output lines denote the i.e. aspec ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are relying on the `word splitting` in the `read` command,
succesive empty values are put together to cause inconsistency in the result.

Would you please try instead:

```
# no changes in your original template
template="General;%OverallBitRate/String%|
Video;%Width%|%Height%|%FrameRate/String%|%DisplayAspectRatio/String%|%ScanType/String%|%FrameRate/String%|%ChromaSubsampling/String%|%BitDepth%|%InternetMediaType%|%Format/String%|%Format_Profile%|%Format_Settings%|%BitRate_Mode/String%|%BitRate_Nominal/String%|%BitRate_Maximum/String%|%ColorSpace%|
Audio;%BitRate/String%|%Format/String%|%Channel(s)/String%|%BitRate_Mode/String%|%BitRate/String%|%SamplingRate/String%"

mapfile -t info < <(mediainfo --Output="$template" "$1" | sed 's/video\///g' | tr '|' '\n' | awk '{ print $1 }')

for i in "${info[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

The `mapfile` built-in command reads lines from the standard input
assigning an array (`info` here) to each lines.
It preserves the empty line `as is` then the result has always the same length.
If you want to assign individual scalar variables to the elements of the array,
you can say something like:

```
A="${info[0]}"
B="${info[1]}"
C="${info[2]}"
...
```

although it would be more convenient to treat the array as an array.

Comment: This is PERFECT! Exactly what i wanted. Many thanks

Comment: Good to know it works. Cheers.